# rails precompile assets see error in which file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I trying to precompile assets in production using

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

its says that there is syntax error like

> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "white-space": expected ";", was
>   ": nowrap;"

but there is no info that in which file.

[image: error]

is there anyway that I can see that about which file its talking about.

Answer (score 0):

its assets / stylesheets/  application.scss file . just find white-space and you will get to the exact line.

Comment: Why is it in `assets/stylesheets/application.scss`?